# For Loop Keep the variable

Tags: php, for-loop

I'm trying to keep the for loop variable but I don´t know how, 
This is the code that I use  to make a string like: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 ect.

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 17;  $i++) {
        $str = $i . ',';
    }
```

Than:

```
$str = substr($str, 0, -1);
```

To get rid of the last char.
However, when I call the $str variable out of the for loop, it only outputs 17

Here is the whole code:

```
        for($i = 0; $i <= 17;  $i++) 
        {
            $str = $i . ',';
        }
        $str = substr($str, 0, -1);
        echo $str;
```

So to sum it up, I need the output to be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 without a , at the end...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 17;  $i++) 
{
    // here
    $str .= $i . ',';
}
$str = substr($str, 0, -1);
echo $str;
```

But there is a better way:

```
echo implode(',', range(0, 17));
```

Comment: Ah thanks... Much better way. I thought it was only possible to use implode on arrays :P

Comment: Don't forget to declare the variable first.

Comment: @user2879055 `range(0, 17)` returns an array.